# Warning in R 'is not a factor variable' in package marked

Tags: r

I was following this tutorial (https://jamesepaterson.github.io/jamespatersonblog/2020-04-26_introduction_to_CJS.html) and it worked fine. I tried to apply it to my own data, but when I was using the `process.data` function I encounter a problem as this call:

```r
gm.proc <- process.data(gm.db, model = "CJS", groups = "con")
```

gives me a warning:

> Warning message: In 'process.data(gm.db, model = "CJS", groups = "con")':
> con  is not a factor variable.

Before using the `process.data` function I checked for the class of `con` variable and changed it to a factor:

```r
class(gm.db$con)
[1] "character"
gm.db$con <- as.factor(gm.db$con)
class(gm.db$con)
[1] "factor"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can provide an experimental dataset for others to play with? I am also a new new contributor, so I can't just comment below you post...